# Sorting an array of strings in swift

Tags: ios, sorting, swift

I'm having trouble sorting an array of strings. The array i'm trying to sort derives from all of the keys in an NSMutableDictionary. I think my main problem is that the keys of value "AnyObject" and that's interfering with my sort function. Here is what I've tried so far:

```
    var sections = self.sortedFriends.allKeys
```

**Attempt 1**

```
    sort(&sections) {$0 < $1}
```

**Attempt 2**

```
    self.sectionTitles = sections.sorted({ (str1:NSString, str2:NSString) -> Bool in
                    return str1 < str2
                })
```

I keep getting the error "AnyObject is not a subtype of NSString". In Objective-C it was easy to use the caseInsensitiveCompare function, but that no longer seems to be the case. If someone can help me I'd appreciate it. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to turn your `[AnyObject]` into things that can actually be compared.  You can either do it at the point of fetching the keys:

```
// as? will return nil if any of the keys are not Strings, this substitutes
// an empty array in that case - you may want different handling
var sections = (self.sortedFriends.allKeys as? [String]) ?? []
```

or cast each element individually:

```
// here, if an individual key is not a String, as? will 
// return nil.  nil is always < non-nil
sort(&sections) { ($0 as? String) < ($1 as? String) }
```

The benefit of the latter is it can handle if one individual element isn't a `String` – the `as?` will return `nil` and `nil` is always less than non-nil so your non-string values will group up one end.

With strings specifically, there's one other option:

```
// with the as? String version above, 5 would come before "4"
let nsm = [3:"4", 2:5] as NSMutableDictionary
var sections = nsm.allValues
// but in this case, both are converted to strings and sort correctly
sort(&sections) { toString($0) < toString($1) }
```

Comment: This worked as well, but I chose the other answer for its simplicity. Thanks for the input!

Comment: One problem I am having with the 

    sort(&sections) { ($0 as? String) < ($1 as? String) } 

method is that i'm getting the error "NSArray does not conform to MutableCollectionType". The same error occurs with NSMutableArray

Answer (score 3):

Try casting it to strings because right now, it's really an array of type `[NSObject]`.  Since there's no overload for the `<` operator that accepts `NSObject`, it doesn't know what to do.

```
let sorted = (dict.allKeys as? [String])?.sorted(<)
```

Comment: @user3353890 unfortunately that simplicity is hiding a nasty potential bug – if there are ever any non-`String` keys, this will explode at runtime with an assertion – try  `let nsd = ["Bob":1, 5:2] as NSDictionary; let keys = nsd.allKeys as [String]`.  In fact, in the 1.2 beta, this kind of `as` was renamed to `as!` to indicate it’s dangerous and probably best avoided.

Comment: @AirspeedVelocity Ick, yeah that doesn't sound good. The way the rest of my code is written however, there shouldn't be any non string keys included in the dictionary. I see what you are saying though, thanks for the insight! I'll most likely change my code just to be safe

Comment: This answer now accounts for all possible nil errors or cast fails.